# Why does iterating unordered::map and adding new elements does not lead to an infinte loop?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, unordered-map

I am iterating through a `std::unordered_map`

```
    std::unordered_map<int, char> mp;
    mp[0] = 'a';
    int i = 1;
    for(auto it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->second<<" ";
        mp[i++] = (char)(97+i);
    }
```

Output

```
a
```

Now as a new element is being added at the end of each iteration I assumed this would run into an infinite loop however as shown in the output it did not.

1. [By seeing this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195233/time-complexity-of-iterating-through-a-c-unordered-map) I realized that the iteration of `std::unordered_map` occurs by iterating through the buckets. So does that mean that in my code, the new value inserted into my map `pair<int,char>(1,'b')` was hashed to a bucket before the bucket of the value `pair<int,char>(0,'a')`"
2. If yes then what happens if load factor exceeds `max_load_factor` and the unordered_map rehashes? Does the whole unordered_map iterate again?

Comment: If `operator[]` call causes rehashing, then all iterators are invalidated and the program exhibits undefined behavior as soon as it executes `it++`. If `operator[]` does not cause rehashing, then iterators remain valid. But since `unordered_map` is, well, unordered, there's no telling whether the new element is inserted before or after the one the iterator points to, and so the loop may or may not encounter it on subsequent iterations.

Comment: If `size() < max_load_factor()*bucket_count()` it's safe to insert and the iterator will remain valid, no matter if the insertion is done before or after the one the iterator points to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's what I said, didn't I?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, I misread, sorry - I removed your name-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting new elements invalidates your iterators at some point, however, you use them again, hence UB

For details, See
[Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) and [iterator invalidation in map C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895485/iterator-invalidation-in-map-c)

To see such behavior, use the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>


int main(){
    std::unordered_map<int, char> mp;
    mp[0] = 'a';
    int i = 1;
    for(auto it = mp.begin(); it!= mp.end();)
    {
        it = mp.insert({i++, (char)(97+i)}).first;
        std::cout<<it->second<<" ";

    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean inserting elements or just when inserting elements leads to rehashing as Igor said above?

Comment: "_Inserting elements invalidates your iterators_" isn't exactly what it says in the link you shared: "_The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not affect the validity of iterators if `(N+n) <= z * B`, where `N` is the number of elements in the container prior to the insert operation, `n` is the number of elements inserted, `B` is the container’s bucket count, and `z` is the container’s maximum load factor._" - That is, iterators are only invalidated if the new `size()`  is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think the answer doesn't have to include everything.

Comment: I agree but it's good if what is included is correct.